# cmake problems with qt creator hello world

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

How can I choose platform for cmake with QT creator?

This is my project settings:

[image]

My cmake settings (what i am supposed to put as platform/kit?):

[image]

This gives me gives me crazy output here:

[image]

[image]

Whats wrong here? I do have rc.exe in my path:

[image]

UPD: As asked, I've checked vcvars32.bat:

[image]

(what am I expected to see here also??):

[image]

Comment: CMake scenario commands want to access Visual Studio Environment to start `rc.exe` and you can set it up before launching VS (otherwise unclear how). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx Create bat file and do `call vcvarsall.bat` before calling VS IDE executable from that bat file.

Comment: Go to `compiler`, Checking did the `initialization` indicate correct `vcvarsall.bat`

Comment: @AlexanderV I am not calling VS IDE executable, I am clicking build in GUI, so its not clear how to use vcvarsall.bat

Comment: @Jiu what do you mean by checking? I have some vcvarsall.bat there.

Comment: there shall be only one `vcvarsall.bat`. Check the file path is exist or not which defined in Qt IDE initialization.

Comment: @StepanYakovenko One way is with VS IDE process environment set. Start VS IDE from some command processor with environment set. The other way is setting variables locally for CMake as Jiu tries to explain but I am not sure. RC.exe must be accessible.

Comment: rc.exe is accessible. Is there a way to fix the problem from QTCreator IDE?

Comment: I tried to reprocess the issue...but everything works perfectly...Qt 5.10.1 + MSVC2015 + cmake 3.11 and a simple HelloWorld with exactly same setting as you post https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/cmake-manual.html

Comment: How do you set up cmake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to walkaround the problem in the end by removing MSVC2017, Windows SDK and reinstalling MSVC 2015 + Windows SDK for W10. But this is not enough, in this crazy dialog:

[image]

you have to select ...ninja+codeblocks and this allows to run cmake sucessfully. Why VS14 setting here causes problems -- this remains a mystery for me.